# melt and merge several files into a single database using R

Tags: r, merge, reshape2, melt

I have been trying to import several csv files, use the function "melt" and merge them into a single database in R. All the files have an "id", "date.time" and "tag" column; however, the rest of the columns differ among files. This is an example of a few lines in one the file:

> ```
>                date.time   tag 111015 111016 113949 113950
> 1 1 2012-10-11 00:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
> 2 2 2012-10-11 01:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
> 3 3 2012-10-11 02:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
> 4 4 2012-10-11 03:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
> 5 5 2012-10-11 04:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
> 6 6 2012-10-11 05:00:00 14767      0      0      0      0
>
> library(reshape2)
>
> # Import files
>
> files<-list.files()
> data<-lapply(files,read.csv,header=TRUE,sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
> ```

I am trying to use this loop to melt each file and bind the resulting data frame. However, its only working for the last file in the loop. I don't know exactly how to set the loop/function so that it can perform first the "melt" of each file and them "merge/bind" them into a single data frame.

> ```
> for(j in 1:length(data)){
>    dm<-melt(data[[j]],measure.vars=c(4:length(data[[j]])),
>      id=c("date.time","tag"),variable.name="receiver")
>
>    results<-rbind(dm)   
>
>   }
> ```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to do using `lapply` to load everything first and then use `melt` as follows: (Assuming all your files are in the variable `files`,

```
Note: Untested 
require(reshape2)
files <- list.files(my.dir, full.names = TRUE)
# first load all files
dd <- lapply(1:length(files), function(idx) {
    d <-read.csv(files[idx], header = TRUE, sep=",", check.names = FALSE)
    # if you want the file index
    d$file.idx <- idx
    d
})
# merge all
dd <- do.call(rbind, dd)
# now melt
dd.m <- melt(dd, c(4:length(d)), c("date.time","tag"), variable.name = "receiver")
```

Edit: After Op's edit

```
Note: Untested 
require(reshape2)
files <- list.files(my.dir, full.names = TRUE)
dd.m <- lapply(1:length(files), function(idx) {
    # load the file
    d <-read.csv(files[idx], header = TRUE, sep=",", check.names = FALSE)
    # now melt immediately
    d.m <- melt(d, c("date.time","tag"), c(4:length(d)))
})
# merge all
dd.m <- do.call(rbind, dd.m)
```

Comment: For some reason its giving me an error "Error: measure variables not found in data: NA" after I try to use the function melt. Now, I would prefer to melt the files first and then do the merge because each file has different row numbers and although each has an "id", "date.time" and "tag" column, the rest of the columns representing counts for different receiver numbers vary between 2 and 6. But if you do the melt then merging them after should be easier.

Comment: What would be the best way to keep the format of each variable (for example, date/time format, numeric, interval, etc) when using melt/rbind? The problem with rbind is that it changes the format of each variable ("date.time" as character, "variable" as character, etc..). Can you do something similar to do.call(rbind, dd.m) with merge instead?